# The jQuery form .submit handler is not working

Tags: jquery

I need to make GET ajax request while form is being submitted. The page should not be reloaded. Tried to attach jQuery `.submit()` handler but for some reason this does not work. Why?

```
...
 $('#login-form').submit(function(){
            e.preventDefault();
            alert('Hi');
                   ....
         });
...

<form id="login-form" class="navbar-form" action="" method="get" >
                            <input id="email" class="span2" type="text" placeholder="Email">
                            <input id="password" class="span2" type="password" placeholder="Password">
                            <button type="submit" id="login-btn" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>

                        </form >
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot the `e` argument in the callback.

```
$('#login-form').submit(function(){
```

should be

```
$('#login-form').submit(function(e){
                                 ^
```

After that it should work. If it doesn't make sure that you bind the handler either inside a document ready event or after the form has been defined.